# How to setup bitrot protection with ext4 on 2 SSD workstation?

Tags: ssd, raid, mdadm

I'm surprised at the lack of documentation on this. Most bitrot protection schemes seem to be oriented at NAS.

I'm thinking of doing the following:

- format a raid1 with mdadm
- install ext4 (64bit?) with checksums enabled
- profit?

I expect to be able to silently corrupt a drive and have the system fix it occasionally. Yes, I have ECC memory and the drives are the same size.

Comment: Profit!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using any standard RAID-configuration other than RAID-0. Setup a LVM RAID with the two disk mirroring each other. You may want to create some small non-mirrored partitions for non-persistent storage purposes like /tmp, ~/.cache, and ~/Downloads as its pointless to set aside double-space allocations for this type of data.

Once you have a LVM mirror setup you can periodically scrub the drives to check for and correct flipped bits. [Red Hat's documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/raid-scrub) will help you out.

I recommend you also have multiple backups of your data as wel. Don't overwrite your backups! Keep revisions. Have multiple backups on multiple medias using multiple backup methods.

Answer (score 1):

Parchive (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive) works on the file level (not on the file system level) and can correct errors by adding redundancy. It is non-invasive, configurable and I use it in a cron job.